# session set in jquery cant able to get in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, session-variables

> **index.js file**

```
sessionStorage.setItem('name', 'xxxx');
```

> **login.php**

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?>
```

in my **index.html** page i get the name and store it in session using javascript

after the page will navigate to **login.php** in that i cant able to get the session variable

pls do help me to solve the issue.

Comment: javascript session and php session is both different things . you can not get local storeage value using PHP

Comment: if the object name is `sessionStorage` than it doesnt mean that it is storing values to server's session

Comment: `sessionStorage` and PHP `$_SESSION` are completely unrelated. The first one lives in the browser (client-side) and the second on the server (server-side). They can't interact directly with each other whatsoever. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: `SessionStorage` and `LocalStorage` allows to save key/value pairs in a web browser

Comment: session is based on browser only so .php file can able to get that browser session...?, set using js

Comment: Not unless you deliberately send this value to the server with an ajax call or something. Client and server are two separated worlds that communicate through requests.

Answer (score 1):

In your index.html file create an ajax request and send it to any php file and in that php file set your session, Then in login.php file you can get you session easily.

Answer (score 1):

javascript session( Local storage ) and php session is both different things . you can not get local storeage value using PHP.

[sessionStorage(localStorage)](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) is not create session . it save value in browser.

if you want to use this stored value to using in PHP then use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). get value from browser local storage and pass to PHP using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request